# Are polynomials open maps w.r.t. the Zariski topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I am super new to algebraic geometry, so I have the following simple question. Are polynomial maps between affine varieties open with regards to the Zariski topology?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Regular maps do not need to be either open or closed with respect to the Zariski topology, as shown in the linked duplicate where an example of a non-closed, non-open map is given.